# Passing containers by value or by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am aware of the differences between pass by value, reference or pointer in the general case. However, my question is about special case about a container with simple structure.

Assuming this case:

```
class image{
    image()=default;
    image(image const&)=default;
    ~image()=default;

    int w;
    int h;
    uchar* data;
}
```

When passing an object of this class what copied are just two integers and pointer not the whole data. In this case is there purpose to passing it by reference ? Or is there a purpose to not passing it by reference?

The thing that triggered this question is that I have read that `iterators` in C++ were designed to be light and to be passed by value. So, I think that this concept may be applied to classes that represent a container to actual data no a data.

Comment: What is `uchar* data` ? I mean Is  it a resource to deep copy and clean ?

Comment: when copying (not cloning) just the pointer will be copied and both object will share the same actual data

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @HumamHelfawi that's not how you should write classes, copy should mean copy and move should mean move. Copies can share ownership of resources through stuff like `shared_ptr` but having raw pointers own resources just seems outdated (that doesn't mean there shouldn't be raw pointers, they just shouldn't own resources).

Comment: The default destructor doesn't delete `data`, so apparently the pointer points to some external (to the class) resource. Copying such a pointer can be quite ok. Perhaps `w` and `h` refers to some specific part of the pointed to data, similar to a `string_view`?

Comment: and if that class is just a view onto memory managed elsewhere you should probably call it "imageView" to indicate that it merely represents a view onto image data, instead of representing image data itself.

Comment: @BoPersson he called that thing a "container". I think we can agree that if the memory is managed elsewhere it's basically just a view into that memory just like iterators basically a view into containers. But people don't usually call iterators containers themselves.

Comment: Sorry guys for this rubbish example. i just need to clarify the idea with minimal example. it is not private of course. no memory leaks because I am going to use smart pointers.. everything not related to the problem will be solved in a way or another

Comment: @HumamHelfawi depending on the smart pointer my answer might change though. I mean if you copy it and you have a shared_ptr then you might incur some cost if you call that function a lot and especially when it's in different threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imho, the best guidelines on how to pass arguments can be found in Herb Sutters excellent talk  [Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64&feature=youtu.be). In your particular case, passing by value would be the best option, as your struct is cheap to copy.

[image: cpp parameter passing overview].

Comment: You could even argue that this struct is also "cheap to move" - especially if it has a managed pointer like `unique_ptr` which is guaranteed to support move properly, and suggest to pass it in by reference. I would think that this particular example is so small that both arguments / decisions are equally valid.

Comment: It isn't just the copying cost that is important; distinct objects get more optimization opportunities because the compiler is allowed to assume that nothing else can point/refer to that object.  For example:

`
int gi;

int val(int i)
{
 gi += i;
 gi += i;
 return i;
}

int ref(const int& i)
{
 gi += i;
 gi += i;

 return i;
}

int main()
{
 gi = 2;
 std::cout << val(gi) << std::endl;  // outputs 2

 gi = 2;
 std::cout << ref(gi) << std::endl;  // outputs 8
}
`

In ref(), the compiler cannot assume the value of i doesn't change.

Answer (score 5):

With the default copy constructor, any copy will be shallow and will not make a copy of the memory pointed *to* by `data`. So when you pass by reference, only the two integers and pointer will be passed, for a total of approximately [12 bytes](http://ideone.com/lPSVga) (depending on your architecture, *i.e.* pointer size).

That difference is so small, that it does not really matter whether you pass it by value or by reference. The latter may be *slightly* faster because the pointer can probably always be passed in via a CPU register and the 12 bytes *may* not, but that is really micro-optimization.

Personally I pass anything but primitive types by (`const`) reference, by default, unless I have a reason not to (see [jupp0r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35032535/2920343)). Major advantage during development is that as the class grows I don't have to worry about when it becomes *too* big and change all my functions to pass by reference.

As far as the default C++ iterators go: note that they are *meant* to basically be just pointers. In fact I know that for Microsoft Visual C++ compiling in Release mode with optimizations enabled, iterators for contiguous data structures such as `std::vector` will reduce to just that. I am not aware if other compilers do this as well, I would think so. However you will notice that if you disable optimizations, then suddenly there is a difference between writing `it++` and `++it` in loop increments, for example - purely because of the additional copy operation in the former case. So even "cheap to copy" may have an impact if you do it often enough. As usual: when worried about performance, measure and decide based on the numbers.

Comment: Iterators for anything other than contiguous data structures cannot reduce to just pointers, as they have different semantics.